# Can Apache HTTP server work as thread-per-request?

Tags: connection, apache2, threads, multi-threading

I'm trying to fully understand the differences between Apache and Nginx. I've come across the concepts of [thread-per-connection and thread-per-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217524/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-per-connection-vs-thread-per-request). Then, I've also learned about [Apache's MPMs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-vs-nginx-practical-considerations). From my understanding, using mpm_prefork, Apache will work on a process-per-connection mode, and using mpm_worker on a thread-per-connection mode.

But there is no way of having Apache being thread-per-request. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You want the 'event' MPM: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html
"A variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming threads only for connections with active processing"